Pair *types* in Dart?
I want to specify a time series as essentially a List of (double, double) pairs; but I'd like to abstract the doubles to the more meaningful types, datetime and value. But Dart objects. It complains (on the last line of code) that neither (datetime, value), i.e., a pair of types, nor dartx Pair(datetime, value) is a type, so neither can serve as a generic type parameter to the List type. What's the right way to express what I want to say here -- to pass a pair type to the list type builder?
const datetime = double; 
const datavalue = double; 
const pointType = Pair(datetime, datavalue); 
const timeSeriesType = List<pointType>; // nope


Another option would be to use a record with named parameters as your pair. Using this approach you would indicate what the parameters mean by using a name (the type is anyway just a double).
typedef DataPoint = ({double dateTime, double value});

void main(List<String> args) {
  final timeSeries = <DataPoint>[];

  timeSeries.add((dateTime: 44545.0, value: 78.9));

  print(timeSeries); // Prints: [(dateTime: 44545.0, value: 78.9)]
  print(timeSeries[0].dateTime); // Prints: 44545.0
  print(timeSeries[0].value); // Prints: 78.9
}


The answer is to use typedef instead of just assigning types to variables. (I'm coming from Lean prover / type theory.)
typedef datetime = double; 
typedef datavalue = double; 
typedef pointType = Pair(datetime, datavalue); 
typedef seriesType = List<(datetime, datavalue)>; // yep!


These are bad names for types since they go against normal Dart naming conventions and especially since DateTime is a standard type, which is confusing.  It's also not clear why you have some separate Pair class instead of doing typedef pointType = (datetime, datevalue);  nor why you don't use typedef seriesType = List<pointType>;.
